# Plot formatting by using variables in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Python mainly for data analysis and have been plotting a lot lately with a lot of formatting.
Something like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_table(...)
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
fig1.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.6)
ax1 = fig1.subplot(121)
ax1.plot(data...)
ax2 = fig1.subplot(122)
ax2.plot(data...)
```

While doing a lot of subplot stuff I had to make use of .subplots_adjust(). Passing the parameters by simply copying an existing line works, but makes uniform formatting after that take more effort.

Is there a way to pass the formatting kwargs to the figure while having them defined somewhere centrally to easily change them later? Maybe by creating a template and using it when creating the figure?

I tried out to create a subclass of a **F**igure template, but didn't make it happen as **f**igure holds the formatting information (although they are set by the .adjust_subplots function, so I don't know if they are technically attributes). I suggest somewhere in between there is a solution, but I'm not that firm in oo-programming and the class structure of matplotlib.

Also tried out to pass the kwargs with a dictionary:

```
plotspacing = {
  "left": 0.1,
  "right": 0.9,
  "top": 0.9,
  "bottom": 0.1,
  "wspace": 0.4,
  "hspace": 0.6
}
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
fig1.subplots_adjust(plotspacing)
```

Comment: With your latter option, just change `fig1.subplots_adjust(plotspacing)` to `fig1.subplots_adjust(**plotspacing)`. The `**` before `plotspacing` expands out the dictionary into keyword-value pairs when passing them to the function.

Answer (score 0):

#### Could you create an "adjuster" function?

```
def adjust_subplots(plot_handle):
    plot_handle.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.6)
```

Then, after each plot you create, you can call it with the handle of the plot.

```
adjust_subplots(fig1)
```